# When using jQuery's click event on a class, how can I avoid calling the event for all with that class name?

Tags: jquery, events, class, click

I am sorry for the poorly worded question, but if you look at the code, what I am asking is really quite simple.

```
$(".toggle").click(function () { 
    var togg = $(this).attr( 'id' );
    if( $(this).text() == 'Read More >>' )
    {
        $("." + togg).addClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );
        $("." + togg).removeClass( togg , 2000 );
        $(this).text('Read Less >>');
    }
    else if( $(this).text() == 'Read Less >>' )
    {
        $(".myBlurbExpanded").addClass( togg , 2000 );
        $(".myBlurbExpanded").removeClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );
        $(this).text('Read More >>');
    }
   });
```

My page has a bunch of biographies on different people next to their picture.  I do not want the entire bio to be visible, so there is a 'show more' and 'show less' link.  The 'show more/less' link has a class of '.toggle'.  So every time this click is executed, all of the biographies expand.  How can I limit the biography expansion to only the one which is clicked.  Am I going about it the wrong way by adding the .toggle class to the link.  Thanks!

Thank you for the responses.

First, here is an example of my html

```
<div class="teamInfo">
    <h3 class="lightblue">John Doe</h3>
    <p class="lightblue"><strong>Programmer</strong></p>
    <div class="myBlurb8">
      information about this person
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="myBlurb8" class="toggle">Read More >></a>
</div>
```

Next, I will try to change . + togg to (this) and see what happens.

Cheers!

Comment: What happens when you change `$("." + togg).addClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );` to `$(this).addClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );`?

Comment: Without seeing an example of the HTML markup it is hard to give you anything other than suggestions on how you could do it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign a variable to the click function's event and then use the `event.target` instead of `this` like so:

```
$(".toggle").click(function (event) { 
    var $target = $(event.target);
    var togg = $target.attr( 'id' );
    if( $target.text() == 'Read More >>' )
    {
        $("." + togg).addClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );
        $("." + togg).removeClass( togg , 2000 );
        $target.text('Read Less >>');
    }
    else if( $target.text() == 'Read Less >>' )
    {
        $(".myBlurbExpanded").addClass( togg , 2000 );
        $(".myBlurbExpanded").removeClass( "myBlurbExpanded" , 2000 );
        $target.text('Read More >>');
    }
});
```